# SOLR: (field-based) relative Term Frequency driving result order

Tags: solr

We are consolidating all our collected content on a record in a single content field, which is the main source for SOLR. The problem is that for some records the content field has only 100K characters, for others 10M or more.

As a result, a search on any term will push 10M character records to the top of the result list.

We would like to limit/counterbalance that by introducing something like "relative term frequency" eg the number of occurrences divided by total number of words in the content field.
Since we don't know what terms people will search on, (I think) we cannot calculate this at indexing time.

Any suggestions/ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the [Custom Similarity](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#Similarity) class.
This would allow you to modify the above parameters and scoring factors.
You need to check the `tf` (term frequency) method and customized it.
The Custom Similarity class can be refereed from the Schema.xml file.

Check the [lucene DefaultSimilarity](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/3.0.0/org/apache/lucene/search/DefaultSimilarity.java) class for reference which is the actual implementation.

Also check [Changing Similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_4_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#changingSimilarity)